# WordPress Redirection Plugin case insensitive regular expression

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I am a total regex rookie and I'm trying to take advantage of the regex option in the WordPress Redirection plugin to have a case insensitive match of a word so that:
www.mydomain.com/someword will redirect to an appropriate paypal page.

by case insensitive I mean any and all variations of capitalization (e.g SomeWord, somEWord, SomeworD, etc)

I've tried:

```
(?:^|\W)someword(?:$|\W)
(?:^|\W)someword(?:$|\W)
^/(\b\Wsomeword\W\b)
^/(\W\bsomeword\b\W)
^/(?i\bsomeword\b)
/(\bS|sO|oM|mE|eW|wO|oR|rD|d\b)
```

but I'm really just dicking around. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(?i)/someword` should work according to [this article](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-redirection-proper-way-to-input-urls-containing-spaces).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me explain what each of your attempts mean:

- `(?:^|\W)someword(?:$|\W)` - either the start of the string or one non-word character, followed by *someword*, followed by the end of the string or a non-word character
- `^/(\b\Wsomeword\W\b)` - the start of the string, forward slash, followed by a word boundary, followed by a non-word character (you already have a contradiction here), followed by *someword*, followed by a non-word character, followed by a word boundary
- `^/(\W\bsomeword\b\W)` - same with non-word characters and word boundaries switched
- `^/(?i\bsomeword\b)` start of string, followed by forward slash, followed by ?!
- `/(\bS|sO|oM|mE|eW|wO|oR|rD|d\b)` - forward slash, followed by either a word boundary and `S` or `sO` or `oM` or `mE` or `eW` or `wO` or `oR` or `rD` or `d` and a word boundary

Word character - either an English letter, a digit or underscore.

Word boundary - a place where on one side you have a word character and on the other, something, which is not a word character.

---

Now as for a solution:

```
(?i)\/someword$
```

Meaning case insensitive, there is a slash and *someword*, followed by the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you, not only for the solution, but for taking the time to explain what my rookie attempts mean.  Regular expressions are always one of those things I'm going to get to someday soon - but I don't really need them that often - even today's example was a bit of overkill and really just my need to make things as perfect as possible (why only cover the obvious variations when you can cover them all).  Anyway thanks again.

Comment: @LeeMandell, happy to help.

Comment: Where do you add that RegEx? I am trying to use Yoast SEO to redirect but entering `/TEst` doesn't work but `/test` does.